Does a better upper bound exist?
Recently, I have been working on a control problem that requires analyzing the convergence rate. However, due to the use of multiple inequalities, the lower bound of the parameter related to the convergence speed is only shown to be positive without a clear mathematical expression, limiting its applicability. This issue can be summarized as the following algebraic problem.
Given that $M_1, \ldots, M_n$ are $n$-dimensional vectors and they are linearly independent.
If $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ are $n$-dimensional vectors such that $\langle y_i, M_i \rangle = 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, and $\|y_1\|^2 + \cdots + \|y_n\|^2 = 1$.
Generally, it is not difficult to show that $\|\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\|^2< n$. I wonder if there is a better upper bound $U^*$ such that:
$$\|\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\|^2\leq U^*< n,$$
of which $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm of a vector.

Thank you very much for your response!
Please let me explain further. I guess that a tighter bound related to $M_i$ may exist.
Consider a 2-dimensional situation: $M_1=[1,0]^T$ and $M_2=[1,-1]^T$. Assume $y_1=[y_{11},y_{12}]^T$ and $y_2=[y_{21},y_{22}]^T$ Notice $<y_1,M_1>=y_{11}=0$ and $<y_2,M_2>=y_{21}-y_{22}=0$. One can express $y_1$ and $y_2$ as:
$$y_1=[0,\alpha]^T,~y_2=[\beta,\beta]^T.$$
Also, $|y_1|^2+|y_2|^2=1$ results that $\alpha^2+2\beta^2=1$.

(Continue)
So, $|y_1+y_2|^2=\beta^2+(\alpha+\beta)^2=\alpha^2+2\beta^2+2\alpha\beta=1+2\alpha\beta\leq 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|2\sqrt{2}\alpha\beta|\leq 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<2$.

Reformulating this as: ${M_1,...,M_n}\subseteq V$  are linearly independent, $V$ a vector space; and ${y_1,...,y_n}\subseteq V$ satisfy $\langle y_i,M_i\rangle=0$... Considering the vectors $y_1=(0,2)$ and $y_2=(2,0)$ in $\mathbb{Q}^2$, alongside with the canonical basis, we  get $||y_1+y_2||^2=8\wedge8>2$... That seems to be a counterexample of your "provable statement".

Dear Yves Daoust, thanks for your comment.
$1+\frac{1}{2}$ is a better bound comparing with 2.
For the original problem, a general bound is $n$ instead of $1$.
If we forget the linearly independent condition, take $y_i=[\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n}]^T,i=1,...,n.$ Then, $|y_1+...+y_n|^2=|[1,...,1]^T|^2=n$

Dear Simon Flavio Ibanez, thanks for your comment. There is an extra condition: $|y_1|^2+...+|y_n|^2=1$. Hence, in your example, it should be like $y_1=[0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]^T, y_2=[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0]^T$. Then, $|y_1+y_2|^2=|[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]|^2=1$.

Sorry, it should be $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

If you want your $U^\ast$ to be independent of ${M_i}$, then no, no such tighter upper bound exists. As long as $n \geq 2$, you can get $|\sum_i y_i|^2$ as close to $n$ as you want.

@DavidGao Thank you very much! Yes, $U^$ should depend on ${M_i}.$ However, how to specify the exact relationship between $U^$ and ${M_i}$ is not clear.

@YvesDaoust It’s a quite understandable mistake. Especially looking from a probability point of view, when applying Cauchy-Schwarz it is quite easy to forget the all $1$ vector only has norm $1$ when it’s a probability space, not in general. I often make that mistake myself in the context of Frobenius norm of matrices.

@Jackie Probably have something to do with the Gram matrix of ${M_i}$, though the exact relation is not clear to me.

@DavidGao: Thank you for your response. Currently, I am working with the index $\min_{z_k,z_k\in Ker(M_k),k=1,...,n}\max_{i\neq j}{\theta_{ij}=\angle(z_i,z_j),~i,j=1,...,n}$. I will also explore using the Gram matrix to see if any analytical relationships can be deduced.

The condition about $M$ does not seem useful. Given any $y_1,\ldots,y_n\in\mathbb R^n$, we can always find a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ such that the $i$-th basis vector is orthogonal to $y_i$.

Write $\mathbf{m}_i = M_i / \|M_i\|$, and let $\lambda$ denote the largest value of OP's sum:
\begin{align*}
\lambda
&= \max\biggl\{ \biggl\| \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{y}_k \biggr\|^2 : \mathbf{y}_k \perp \mathbf{m}_k \text{ and } \sum_{k=1}^{n} \|\mathbf{y}_k\|^2 = 1 \biggr\}
\end{align*}
Also, let $\mathbf{M} = [\mathbf{m}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{m}_n]$ the $n\times n$ matrix with the $k$th column being the column vector $\mathbf{m}_k$. We claim:
$$ \lambda \leq n - \underbrace{ \min_{\|\mathbf{v}\| = 1} \| \mathbf{M}^{\top}\mathbf{v}\|^2 }_{=\sigma_n(\mathbf{M})^2}, $$
where $\sigma_n(\mathbf{M})$ is the smallest singular value of $\mathbf{M}$. The linked article contains some discussion about the general properties of the smallest singular value, which might possibly be useful in OP's case.

To this end, we consider the corresponding Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L} = \biggl\| \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{y}_k \biggr\|^2
- \alpha \sum_{k=1}^{n} \|\mathbf{y}_k\|^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \beta_k \langle \mathbf{y}_k, \mathbf{m}_k \rangle.
$$
Then by writing $\mathbf{s} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{y}_k$, we get
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\mathbf{y}_k} \mathcal{L}
&= 2\mathbf{s} - 2\alpha \mathbf{y}_k - \beta_k \mathbf{m}_k, \quad \forall k, \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Now, assume that $(\mathbf{y}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{y}_n)$ maximizes $\|\mathbf{s}\|^2 $ under the constraints
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \|\mathbf{y}_k\|^2 = 1, \qquad
\langle \mathbf{y}_k, \mathbf{m}_k \rangle = 0, \quad \forall k. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Then we know that $\text{(1)}$, the the partial derivatives of $\mathcal{L}$, vanish at that maximizer point. From these, we observe:

Taking inner product between $\text{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{y}_k$, we get
$$ 0 = 2\langle \mathbf{y}_k, \mathbf{s} \rangle - 2\alpha \|\mathbf{y}_k\|^2. $$
Summing this for $k = 1, \ldots, n$, this implies that $\alpha = \|\mathbf{s}\|^2 = \lambda$.

Taking inner product between $\text{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{m}_k$, we find that
$$ \beta_k = 2\langle \mathbf{m}_k, \mathbf{s} \rangle. $$

Combining altogether,
$$ \mathbf{s} = \lambda \mathbf{y}_k + \mathbf{m}_k \mathbf{m}_k^{\top} \mathbf{s}. $$
Summing both sides for $k = 1, \ldots, n$, we get
$$ n\mathbf{s} = \lambda \mathbf{s} + \mathbf{M}\mathbf{M}^{\top} \mathbf{s}. $$
In particular, it follows that $\mathbf{s}$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{M}^{\top}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $n-\lambda$.


The above calculation shows that $n - \lambda$ is at least as large as the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{M}^{\top}$. Therefore
$$ \lambda = n - (n - \lambda) \leq n - \min_{\|\mathbf{v}\| = 1} \| \mathbf{M}^{\top}\mathbf{v}\|^2 $$
as claimed.

Thanks very much for your insightful comment!

The condition $\langle y_i,M_i\rangle=0$ implies:
$$\langle y_i,M_j\rangle=|y_i||M_j|-\delta_{ij}|y_i||M_j|$$
And
$$\langle y_i,M_j\rangle=|y_i|^2\Leftrightarrow y_i=M_j$$
Where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.
Various numeric values seem to imply that the following inequality is true:
$$\Big|\sum_{0<i≤n}y_i\Big|^2≤\Big|\sum_{0<i≤n}y_i\Big|≤\sum_{0<i≤n}|y_i|≤n$$
